# How to bind a table without(edit,delete,create) in mvc contrib grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, mvccontrib

i have used mvccontrib grid in mvc 2.0 
I want to just bind a table in the gridview...so  far my coding is....i dont no whther it is correct or wrong...

Homecontroller.cs:

```
public ActionResult List(int? page)
{
    using (ProductDataContext db = new ProductDataContext())
    {
        ViewData["product"] = db.Products.ToList().AsPagination(page ?? 1, 10);
        return View("product");
    }
}
```

i have also cretaed the list view for that.......
What is coding i should write in Index.aspx

so far i used this coding it is not working......

```
<% Html.Grid((List<Product>)ViewData["product"])
    .Columns(column =>
        {
            column.For(c => c.CategoryID);
            column.For(c => c.SupplierID);

        }).Render(); 
 %>
```

it shows there is no data available. Or is there any other coding?

My issue is just i want to bind table in mvccontrib grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it shows that there's no data available the problem is that `db.Products.ToList().AsPagination(page ?? 1, 10)` simply returns no elements (empty collection). As to why this happens it is impossible to say from the information you provided. It will largely depend on the implementation of this `ProductDataContext` and the available data in your data store.

This being said, I would recommend you using strongly typed views:

```
public ActionResult List(int? page)
{
    using (ProductDataContext db = new ProductDataContext())
    {
        var products = db.Products.ToList().AsPagination(page ?? 1, 10);
        return View("product", products);
    }
}
```

And so your view simply becomes:

```
<%@ Page
    Language="C#" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<AppName.Models.Product>>" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="AppName.Models" %>

<%= Html.Grid<Product>(Model)
        .Columns(column =>
        {
            column.For(c => c.CategoryID);
            column.For(c => c.SupplierID);
        })
%>
```

Notice how the view is strongly typed to a collection of products.

Plain, simple, strongly typed.

---

UPDATE:

As requested in the comments section here's an example of adding *Edit* and *Delete* links to each row:

```
<%= Html.Grid<Product>(Model)
        .Columns(column =>
        {
            column.For("TableLinks").Named("");
            column.For(c => c.CategoryID);
            column.For(c => c.SupplierID);
        })
%>
```

and in the `TableLinks.ascx` partial:

```
<%@ Control 
    Language="C#" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<AppName.Models.Product>" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="AppName.Models" %>

<td>
    <%: Html.ActionLink<ProductsController>(c => c.Edit(Model.Id), "Edit") %> |
    <% using (Html.BeginForm<ProductsController>(c => c.Destroy(Model.Id))) { %>
        <%: Html.HttpMethodOverride(HttpVerbs.Delete) %>
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
    <% } %>
</td>
```

Which assumes of course the following actions are present in your ProductsController:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
...
[HttpDelete]
public ActionResult Destroy(int id)
```

I also invite you to checkout a [sample MVC application](https://github.com/darind/samplemvc/) I wrote which illustrates those concepts.

Comment: How did this answer his question? Granted it's a good idea to use strongly typed views, but in the end, don't yours and his code amount to the same? Both would crash if you assigned something other than a list of products. Other than that, is there any difference in your code (am I simply not spotting it)?

Comment: The difference is in `Html.Grid((List<Product>)ViewData["product"])` vs `Html.Grid<Product>(Model)`. Using ViewData is ugly, requires casting and depends on the actual name used in the controller action.

Comment: can u send some sample edit and delete using mvc contrib grid pls i am new to this

Comment: here is there any need of jquery

Comment: Not using any javascript in my example.

Comment: Mostly in the views (HTML helpers) and controller actions (mainly `AsPagination` extension method).

Comment: which gridview is better in u r point of view either htmlhelpers or

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: i am so helpful in with u r answers in case if i struck pls help me

Comment: which gridview is better by using HTML helpers or mvc contrib grid

Comment: what are the different method of gridview we can use in mvc 2.0

Comment: It depends on your scenario. There are cases where HTML helpers do the job and other cases where MVCContrib Grid is preferred. I can't speak in general, need a concrete scenario.